# Custom forms authentication in a lightswitch application

Tags: silverlight, authentication, wcf-ria-services, visual-studio-lightswitch

We have an existing data source which already includes tables for users (employees) and roles.

Is there a way to use these tables instead of the users and roles tables created by lightswitch when you select forms authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this thread:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitchgeneral/thread/5f2965cf-a6d5-4b31-8ed5-a737fc13bdb9

BTW, the LightSwitch team is active on the Microsoft forums right now. You'll probably have a better bet using that forum for questions until the community builds up more. It's a new product so the team is trying to focus on discussions there right now.

Thanks for evaluating LightSwitch!